# Screenshotting the app with a camera in the view returns a blank image

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code to take a screenshot of the app:

```
    var imageSize = CGSize.zero

    let orientation = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) {
        imageSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    } else {
        imageSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0)
    for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
        window.drawHierarchy(in: window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.captureImageView.image = image
```

This is my code for showing the camera:

```
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.addInput(input)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
    videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
    self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

    let previewLayerConnection: AVCaptureConnection? = videoPreviewLayer?.connection
    if previewLayerConnection?.isVideoOrientationSupported != nil {
        previewLayerConnection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft
    }

    captureSession?.startRunning()
```

I have tried everything from other stackoverflow users with regards to this problem but it's not really working. What could be the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
    window.drawHierarchy(in: window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

Here you are using the window as a screenshot view. By default your window color is `black`, That's why you getting black screenshot.

Use one of your view controller subviews.

Try to get the first screenshot with updated code. Then implement with your camera.

Your code should looks like this

```
view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

Comment: I used your code "view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)" and I put a background color (yellow) to my cameraView where the cameraLayer was added and when I took a screenshot, the image displayed is yellow (which was the cameraView backgroundColor). Why is it not the preview of the camera that is captured?